# Prohibit direct access to a certain page

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, session, url

how to create page that cannot be opened by direct url ?

my [index.php](http://pastebin.com/nRZNLVDk) , 
   [main.php](http://pastebin.com/qDHVpvLy) and [config.php](http://pastebin.com/jvXtySTG)

i want to create data.php to get some result from database tables. but data.php need some coding to :
1. make it secure ( no direct access )
2. get table from sql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For preventing direct access, you can do either of these:

```
if(count(get_included_files()) ==1) exit("error");
```

or

```
debug_backtrace() || die ("error");
```

or

```
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == basename(__FILE__)) die('Error');
```

> The best way to prevent direct access to files is to place them outside of the web-server document root (usually, one level above). You can still include them, but there is no possibility of someone accessing them through an http request.

another way, deny with extension matching:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(inc)$">

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch>
```